# fetch fasta from ncbi via vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, bioinformatics

Is there a way to fetch sequence (with vanilla JS) from NCBI database link?

```
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/KTC77672.1?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text
```

I done this with other database (uniprot) and it worked. But NCBI might have some differences.

```
async function getData(url) {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  return data.text();
}

const test = getData('https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/E5G0U9.fasta').then((r) => console.warn(r));
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    test
</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in your question does not return FASTA format as plain text. It returns HTML using the `pre` tag to make it look like plain text.

You should be using the [NCBI E-utilities API](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/) - in particular, the `efetch` method.

The URI for your example protein looks like this:

https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=KTC77672.1&rettype=fasta

So try that in your Javascript function. Seems to work in my Chrome console (see image).

[image]